# Connection to Mongo Database from Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, mongodb, odbc, ssms

My goal is to connect to a Mongo database from Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) 2014 and be able to perform simple SQL queries.

I'm using Linked Servers connections through ODBC drivers.

I've tried the following drivers for Mongo:

1. [Simba Mongo ODBC driver](http://www.simba.com/connectors/mongodb-odbc) I stuck with error "Required conversion is not supported". But at least I was able to connect to Mongo server and see list of Mongo tables/collections.
2. [Progress Mongo ODBC driver](https://www.progress.com/products/datadirect-connect/odbc-drivers/data-sources/mongodb) I stuck with error "Insufficient information to connect to the data source" (While test from ODBC Administrator is successful).

I would really appreciate any help about establishing connection between Mongo and SSMS.

Maybe you can recommend some specific ODBC driver for Mongo?

Comment: Hi Tamara,

For the Simba driver, the error about the conversion comes up only when you have string columns returned, and you've adjusted the default string column length, correct? If you have adjusted the default string column length, what have you defaulted it to? Linked Server will throw this conversion error if the string columns are over a certain length.

Comment: @KylePorter Hi Kyle. I adjusted it to 16383 symbols - maximum available value. Do you know how can I fix this conversion error?

Comment: I believe you can type values into the length edit boxes, can you specify a value of 7999 and try again? Anything over 8000 becomes a SQL_LONGVARCHAR and linked server then doesn't like it very much.

Comment: @KylePorter Yes, I can input any value into the maximum length boxes. I tried 7999. I didn't receive "conversion is not supported" error, but I again received error about string length "The (maximum) expected data length is 7999, while the returned data length is 8000." The thing is that I have fields in Mongo that can be really long. Can you recommend any solutions?